# vb6 set listview item/subitem image

Tags: image, listview, vb6, subitem

I have a listview that I want to implement the effect seen in this image:

[image: listview with masked item and sumitem]

The listview hides some items like in the image below except a
password is entered.  I know that item and subitem image are usually
left aligned.

How do I set the item and subitem image to cover the whole text are of the list view as shown?

**EDIT**

I got a tip of how to draw the pattern in this pics [from here](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_draw_hatch_samples.html), but how do I draw this on a listitem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be better off using subclassing and owner/custom drawing. That will allow you to draw that entire row and let the listview deal with the rest.

Comment: i don't have much skills subclassing and owner/custom drawing. do you have any good guide?

Comment: Only MSDN, that's what I used to implement something similar a while ago. I'll try and dig out soem sample code but I can't guarantee anything.